# Cannot delete python object instance

Tags: python, object, global

For an example, I have a class A:

```py
def start(): 
    global object
    object = A()

def stop():
    del object
```

I got an error `local variable 'object' referenced before assignment`

I want to store a reference of the newly created object using the start function
and delete the object reference using the stop function.

Is there any way to instantiate an object and delete an object instance using functions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `del` *doesn't delete objects to begin with*

Comment: Don't call your variable `object` (or `list` or `dict` or...) - having said which, your `stop` routine hasn't been told that there is a `global` it should be looking at.

Comment: Anyway, you have to use `global` in `stop`. But be aware, using global mutable state like this is usually considered bad design

Comment: Deleting a variable will only delete the object if it's the only reference to the object.

Comment: Initiate the global variable with None `obj = None` . Then use global on both functions `global obj`. Don't use del. Just set the variable to None instead in the stop function `obj = None`.

Comment: `del` is *rarely* needed. It doesn't delete an object; it removes a name from a scope (or invokes `__delitem__` or `__delattr__` in the case of `del x[i]` or `del x.i`). An object *may* be deleted, if you removed the last reference to the object.

Comment: beside advices from other comments: avoid using global variables if possible, you'll have bad time when your codebase will get bigger.

Comment: thanks guys! I initiated the object with None, use global for both functions and set the variable to None instead for stop function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the name `object` is extremely bad practice because its a python keyword. Don't do that.

To delete globals inside a function you need to redeclare them first. See below.

```
def start(): 
    global obj
    obj = {"dog": True}

def stop():
    global obj # Re-declare.
    del obj
   
start()
print(obj) # {'dog': True}
stop()
print(obj) # NameError: name 'obj' is not defined
```

Note also that the mutation of globals, or deleting them in this case, is *usually* considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
object = None

def start(): 
    global obj
    obj = {"dog": True}

def stop():
    global obj
    obj = None
```

thanks guys! I initiated the object with None, use global for both functions and set the variable to None instead for stop function